# External function call: error 1097 upon changing machine

Tags: dll, labview

I have a LV program that calls an external library via wrapper functions that I downloaded via VI package manager (libxml2). This program works fine on computer A (Win7, LV2015 32-bit). Since it is meant to be portable, I have installed it on various computers (Win7) where it runs well, except for computer B. There, it throws an Error 1097 when calling the external library. The libxml2 package is obviously installed and I can see it on the Functions palette. Could it be due to the differing versions of Windows, or due to conflicts between Labview 32- and 64-bit? I open and run my program with LV 32-bit.

Computer A:
Labview 2015 (32-bit)
Windows 7

Computer B:

Labview 2015 (32-bit)
and Labview 2015 (64-bit)
Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that the call parameters to the dll need to be changed between the 32bit and 64bit labview vi, this is indicative of the error 1097. If you have pointers or need to reserve memory these can have different size between the 64bit and 32bit variants.

For more help code needs to be shown also a more detailed error description if that is provided.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem: probably, there were race conditions and sometimes the DLL was getting illogical random input. It had nothing to do with the system.